# Java - random errors on my semicolon and curly brackets

Tags: java, compiler-errors

this is my first question on Stack Overflow, do comment on how I can improve my question-asking.

So basically I have random errors appearing in my Java code, for the semicolon, curly bracket, and sometimes for other random characters. I have no idea why they keep popping up now and then - they only occur sometimes. I've made sure that all the brackets are paired. Here's an example of when the errors appear :

```
public static *void* main(String[*]* args) *{*
    public class TestClass {
        int num1 = 1;
        int num2 = 1;
        int num3*;*

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            num3 = num1 + num2;
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = num3;
            num3 = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println(num3);
        }

    }
}
```

All the character between asterisks have errors in my code. All of them say : "Syntax error on token :...."
And if rewrite the exact same code somewhere else, the errors disappear
What's going on?

Oh, and the asterisks aren't actually in my code, they stand for the squiggly red underlinings in the original code.

Comment: Do you have any code before the first line you show?

Comment: Can you show the *full* code, including class declaration, imports, comments etc.

Comment: Is the name of the Java file `TestClass`? If so, then main needs to be **inside** the class, and the first two lines would need to be swapped.

Answer (score 1):

You declared class inside of a main method - this is incorrect, you should declare method inside of your class instead - this is an example how you could improve your program to make it work correctly:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = 1;
        int num2 = 1;
        int num3;
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            num3 = num1 + num2;
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = num3;
            num3 = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println(num3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other replies you have your class inside your method, instead of your method inside of your class.

When thinking about object oriented programming, your classes should be the concept you are trying to represent and the methods should be what they do.

For example:

```
public class Dog{
    public void bark(){
        //foo
    }
}
```

Is like saying there's a dog and it can bark.

However:

```
public class Bark{
    public void dog(){
        //foo
    }
}
```

Is like saying there's a bark and it can dog. It doesn't make much sense.

And what you have now is even a bit stranger:

```
public void bark(){
    public class Dog{
        //foo
    }
}
```

Which doesn't have any particular meaning in programming. But the best that I could reason would be that *something* can bark, but also contains a dog. It doesn't make any sense really.

Answer (score 0):

You got the class and main method backwards. The main method goes inside the class:

```
public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    // code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.
1. You are trying to define the method "main" outside of a class. You can't do that.
2. You are trying to define a class inside the main method. That is wrong.
3. You are writing executable code (the loop) inside the class definition but not inside a method of the class.

Answer (score -1):

All of your code needs to be inside

```
public class Main{

}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions that you don't know the answer to.